# How to Create spinner in front of title in android or How to create Spinner in top of an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my project I have 5-6 Activities.

Now I want to set a `Spinner` at the top of an activity, i.e. in the top corner, in front of the title.

Suppose we are in Activity 1: then by using Spinner, in front of the title name, we can go to any of the other activities.

Same thing should happen in all activities.

Please help me how to implement in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ActionBar` then you can add them to the `overflow` menu. If you are not then what I did was to create my own nav bar to `include` in all `Activities`. I created a `BaseActivity` from which to `extend` in other `Activities` and the menu logic can go in that `BaseActivity`. Just create a `layout` for your custom title bar and use the  tag in `Activities` to include that `layout` you can position your `Spinner`, title bar, and whatever else you want inside of it. I hope this helps.

If this isn't what you are talking about then please explain a little more.

Comment: I am using < Fixed + Swipe tab bar navigation > than what to do?

Comment: `include` the custom `layout` at the top of your `layout` files

Answer (score 0):

First you should define a spinner in an xml-file:

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/array_name"
         />
```

With array :

```
<string-array name="array_name">
<item>Activity 1</item>
<item>Activity 2</item>
<item>Activity 3</item>
</string-array>
```

than in the other layouts:

```
<include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/spinner" />
```

in the activites you can add an setOnItemSelectedListener and start the Activity in the callBack-Method

Comment: I done all those things. Now my problem is how to set this Spinner in the front of Title (in the front of activity name)?